# What would cause bootstrap columns to act like rows?

Tags: html, css, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3, col

I cannot figure out why these column classes are not acting properly. They are vertically stacking. I am fairly new to boostrap, so I could be missing something obvious.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

HTML-

```
<div class="row content-container">
        <div class="row top-nav">
            <div class="row header">
                <div class="col-lg-4 logo">
                    <img src="images/logo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 nav-area">
                    <div class="row number">
                        888.888.8888
                    </div>
                    <div class="row navigation">

                    </div>
                    <div class="row heading">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row sub-nav">
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="row content-footer"></div>
    </div>
```

SCSS-

```
.content-container{
        position: relative;
        background-image:url("images/border-vertical.png"), url("images/parchment-bg.jpg"), url("images/border-vertical.png");
        background-position: top left, top center, top right;
        background-origin: border-box, content-box, border-box;
        background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y, repeat-y;
        height: 1500px;
        width: 972px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px 56px 0 56px;

        .nav-area{
            position: relative;

            .number{
                background-image:url("images/phone-number-bg.png")
            }
        }

        .content-footer{
            background-image: url("images/border-horizontal.png");
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
            background-origin:content-box;
            height: 31px;
            width: 892px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 40px;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What dimensions are you viewing the browser at that it's not doing what you expect? Technically you really don't need `row` to do what you want. Typically `col-[size]-[num]` is enough to float divs the way you want.

Comment: I guess the resolution was below the breakpoint for col-lg-*. Is it a feature of bootstrap to have columns automatically stack if the browser resolution is below the breakpoint for the specific column class of divs?

Comment: Yes that how it works if you hit the `col-sm-*` breakpoint which is `< 768`. You may have already seen but [here's the bootstrap grid page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Can I just point that row inside a row can adversely affect your alignment. Same goes for cols under cols.

Comment: I did not know that. Do you mind explaining how the alignment is affected in those situations?

Answer (score 2):

First off, you don't need to put the class row in every div that contained your col-lg-*

But you can still stack them however you want though.
Example :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As for your problem, you were right about the columns breaking up when you reach the min-width of col-lg-*. This is a feature of bootstrap. This prevents your columns shrinking so much that it becomes unreadable.

You could however, add the grid classes for smaller views. Like this:

```
        <div class="row header">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 nav-area">
                <div class="row number">
                    888.888.8888
                </div>
                <div class="row navigation">

                </div>
                <div class="row heading">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```